# Dhtmlx Gantt Chart - Minor Issue

Tags: gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I've set up DHTMLX Gantt Chart (http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml). I'm loading raw xml data as opposed to an xml file.

However, I get an alert saying 'Cannot Parse This XML String'. But when I click 'OK' the Gantt Chart appears as normal.

Below is the code I'm working with:

```
var $_ = jQuery;
$_(document).ready(function() {
window.createChartControl = function(htmlDiv1){
    var ganttChartControl = new GanttChart();
    ganttChartControl.setImagePath("../../../../lib/plugins/html/gui/dhtmlx/gantt/1.3/codebase/imgs/");

    ganttChartControl.create(htmlDiv1);

    var xml_data_str = '<projects><project id="1" name="Project 1" startdate="2006,12,14"><task id="1"><name>Task 1 of Project 1</name><est>2006,12,14</est><duration>20</duration><percentcompleted>20</percentcompleted><predecessortasks></predecessortasks><childtasks><task id="11"><name>Sub Task 1 of Task 1 of Project 1</name><est>2006,12,14</est><duration>5</duration><percentcompleted>10</percentcompleted><predecessortasks></predecessortasks><childtasks></childtasks></task><task id="12"><name>Sub Task 2 of Task 1 of Project 1</name><est>2006,12,15</est><duration>10</duration><percentcompleted>20</percentcompleted><predecessortasks>11</predecessortasks><childtasks></childtasks></task></childtasks></task></project><project id="2" name="Project 2" startdate="2006,12,17"><task id="2"><name>Task 1 of Project 2</name><est>2006,12,17</est><duration>60</duration><percentcompleted>20</percentcompleted><predecessortasks></predecessortasks><childtasks><task id="21"><name>Sub Task 1 of Task 1 of Project 2</name><est>2006,12,17</est><duration>40</duration><percentcompleted>20</percentcompleted><predecessortasks></predecessortasks><childtasks></childtasks></task></childtasks></task></project></projects>';
    ganttChartControl.loadData(xml_data_str, false, false);
    }

window.createChartControl('chart_dhtmlx_gantt_2');
});
```

The relevant bit is the XML data. Is there something wrong with the way I've set it up?!

Kindly assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post on the forum
http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15909&p=48639&hilit=loaddata#p48639

There is a bug in the code ...